# Why I got different result when I encode the same image to base64 String? ( java vs python )

Tags: java, python, image, base64

I'm working on eye project detection using Tensorflow lite on Android.
I have got false values for x and y coordinates of landmarks that should be drawn on the eye region.
So I have tried to follow the original source of the error and I figured out that the problem is coming from the image ( bitmap ).
So I have tried to compare the base64 encoded string of the same image using two functions on Android ( java code ) and on python.
Unfortunately, I have got different results of base64 String encoded.

The image is from 300VW ibug dataset: (112*112)

[image: ibug dataset image]

- Python code:

```py
import os
import base64

image = 'irisdata-300VW_Dataset_2015_12_14-017-000880.jpg'

encoded_string = ""
with open(image, "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    file = encoded_string
    print(encoded_string)
```

- Java code ( Android ):

```java
  public String getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
        // get the base 64 string
        String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return imgString;
    }
 public static String convert(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
        return Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
  myOptions2.inDither = true;
        myOptions2.inScaled = true;
        myOptions2.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;// important
        myOptions2.inPurgeable = true;
        bitt1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image000880);
        Bitmap bitt2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitt1);
        Bitmap bitt3 = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        image2.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmap = image2.getDrawingCache();
        String bs64=getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(bmap);
        Log.i("Bitmap chaine"," new chaine "+bs64);
        String ch=convert(bitt1);
        String ch1=convert(bitt2);
        String ch2=convert(bitt3);
        Log.i("chaine 1",""+ch);
        Log.i("chaine 2",""+ch1);
        Log.i("chaine 3",""+ch2);
```

**Logs**

- Android logcat:

> 2019-08-23 10:46:47.298 30203-30203/com.example.irisdetection I/chaine 1: 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
>   2019-08-23 10:46:47.299 30203-30203/com.example.irisdetection I/chaine 2: 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
>   2019-08-23 10:46:47.300 30203-30203/com.example.irisdetection I/chaine 3: 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

- Python log:

> b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAgICAgQDAgICAgUEBAMEBgUGBgYFBgYGBwkIBgcJBwYGCAsICQoKCgoKBggLDAsKDAkKCgr/2wBDAQICAgICAgUDAwUKBwYHCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgr/wAARCABwAHADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD8lvgv4f0PWtP1i78VWMN1s8E3N5aLN/yzmXhWBzwc5r029tJb39nP4beJfLUK9pfWT/v9xPk3BPK9uJFHPpmuI+EHhbT/ABD/AGPpcl20UWreEdQSUhRlWikbgZ6kjn8a9L8DQ6prf7B2i30s0klroHxJubCLcBiMXFqk2OOcExseaeJpwWHlyqzPc4SxKjnEU9ndH0L+w34d8Qa34Mt/FviS5aXyoPsOmRuTiO2jd2AA7ZZ2/IV9P+HtPKy4vCEjCZrz/wDZd8NaXo3wp0SykYRlNNidsDqzDc36mtr4yfFaw8E6KXtlLsvCRxj5mNc0VCNOyVjyasozxU5R7v8AM2dZvbSe4a1tW4Ld8c1JY+H5NwkikOOxNfMtx8Xvjlrd62oeFPhZrl1Gj9I7Bz39cVq6N+0p+1b4Yu408RfAuRLUtlFuYZFfb74rklT5ps97DVYwSvsfTNvol3bD98QR3FP1O1t/s24Qk57DrWZ8LfjDB4/01ZtV0N7GYxgtE2cfTnvXS32q6FAQzRcgZIpezZ6sJRmvdPPvEOi3flvsTCkcV5xrul3trcMHw3zHGO1dJ8Z/2nvh/wCALuSz1mO6kRGOTaRB8fXJFeI6x+3B8K9T1E2+kaTqToRzJNAqgHn3JpOjK1xPEUYKzZ6x4bgaOEPcCvmL9tv4UXXiXxlY6todvctJPKyXEVuOXABIJ+gBr3z4afFnw58RNLlm0ecLIhwYifmH4Vznxot4JrzS5Q26T7avQ88gjH611ZfLkxMV3PnM2lGpCUux88fDf4VeA/FXw/1bwv4i8f3+h+Io/FljDpkR0dZrV4mik85pJjKvlupUbV2kNu6jFe5f8Eqfg74Y8Mf8Fevhf4L1zXjrNnca1aXLTXthGu+RS7IhSN3X76KAc9815X4Y0nStB+LdxcalqohuIvE9pNb2czBI5kYvvZnPC4GOvrXrH7OHxt0SL/grr8KvHng/VUvI4r6ygddDuEuWVzP5e1AqgFsP9zJJPfkV9aqVsRy+T/I+QrVHOj935nyL+zv4hl0m+8MNDaJeSfZ9Zsltj99CyAgjjrzX0J+w34H1n4nf8E6fjposVtDEvg7xp4c1m4uLhiHgErXVuwAA77QDnpxWd/wSZ/Zosfi14cu/i1rNhHczaNr09t4fiuHIiE7RxtJJIARuCjaADwd5yOBX3B8O/gUl34b1Pwj4eay8PQeJWjh1ZfDcH2OPURB+8jW6iX5JCpBKNjr2BJz87Vr017r6n2GW5dicNBY69kmcz8LdUt18OwadbsN1vBGrIh+7xwK7XWPB/wAOPC/h/wD4Tj4g2cl7MkO77OkZfHOQqrnBP+Neb/s5WC3HiLxcs0m9dO8Uz6ejtxlIG2Djp2r0rVtbku9TYzxExphY+M4x3rkq1I0ldI4sHh1Vm233PIvjj+1Z8VvBnwEvv2gvht8P/DVppOl60umSeH9f1gwavMpGRcJaiMnyO29iOQetVPgv8dvj9+0B4Dk+IsfgPSpdIj1qewxYSvLLPFGob7THE0cchi5PYsu0llGDXsN/4X03x5N9j1Lw/b3OxQBJLbqTjOeuMjn+VZ3ijwl4f8PxIlvpNmxjIYQmENz649aj6xRlq0erTwmJh10M74arqdt4sOk63GkYntvtEAjcMu0jjB78VvfFDxfoPhfRrm+nmdjHCc7R0GKx7D7TYudev7ZISIPLtoolwsadccV5p8WtauNT8P3qF8kggjrkVySrSTaPWwik4s4TWdO8O+Noz4l+IUcVrplxIfJebguM8kcjjmoz8If2TTaedpLQ3JkQl5hfbtp9P3bnH4iut8NRaP8AELwVfeGb7SrWdr3S5LCIahb+cbBXjKFrf5gIzznPXI614f4c/YW1b4c61qN94h1G41RBa/Z9IntlS0FqMfKxCE79o6Z5PUk10wlFwV2cdVSdV2iWtV8OXHwp8Sw+KfhvqErWsb5mtXkDh0z/AHhj8jXb/EnX010aFfaeCPPha5A6bXSJmGfxFYfg34R/EbwzZHTtbvYNVtHYlLmAYcKezKeCfcVY8U3dp4b8SadYSQmRIdLmjjVTgozDaD/OvSyOl9azijS7yPFzpulgJzXY8t+NtvpOteObe+8RadeSWWopBJqMGl8zsu4hhH/telT/AAx0OX9lP9q74a/GTwJ4L1+wtNOu7bVLI+I40WS4uLa4SYqVUkKMKgwcZr6E/ZottGn8fXUl3YwSTv4Nla1kniVvLdLmEhhnpwx54rB/a8+K/gK11jRvhvrmrC+8SxSLcwNHFxCpGCS3QZHb2r73MsLCjn6p9Lo+Hp1pTwL72ML/AIIueO5NS/Z88YeDbJwk+na+06KGyQJ4EUH84TX3Jb+H9R0DwbbatpU7T6hblJ7RBcGNUlBzlsdQOTjvivzM/wCCMXiK68P/ABd8ZfDiS4VX1Kw3QiRsbriFiVXnjOwyflX6gR6Fr6+DrXxJr2txI2liS8ubKOL/AFgRHKx5z0OeeK/Ma8G6i5T9YhXccijCeje3ofLP7DfxGXUvFetabr84IvdfuLuSUthWZ3OfrX1Z4q0TS7nZcWCIy4GGUDn3r86/2RdWuJfE6Wb3skTzKZSVPKuO/Poa+0/hb8S7Fnm8O6jr5ultpCheRSW3cenFXUgpU+Vny+ErOlX0fU6G6tXt4mSKeRCeAVPSse98Pva2R1K/lWKDd8zyuAW/OupultZiZo2/dgZU+1cV491vQFmtJfEUdzcadb3Ae7htj8xTaR+AziuKMYqdj7de/SuuxQ8V3j3UcS6D++iVQGbqCfrXBeKPD19qts9vHZgSP6jGTXS2n7VHh1bl/Dtx8GrjTdChb/Q9YzDKkj9g5VvMQkA/eG0+ua4T4/8A7Z/gSW2trHwJ4cji1N5Qq2+mRyzSMAeW2ZZvr0FaVKKjsc+EqqlFxktRvgXQdR0pft8MORDKVnRRnBB6Gu11y/07XdJLxSBJAuGB9a5v9nzxy/i8315DCwjmCm8SdcFZWAzgHp06etaXiKzfT7iaO2PybjjNcsou1jvioNambpElrar5MzqccbjXiPxV8RaFP8UZNPvrpLdI7fKSkZ+ZnAC4Hrz+Vdt4w8T22jK811e+Vt7CvKPA+kXnxc8Xa/4p3KsFu0VnECc53ByT+AHP+9XbgauKwVVV6LtKOzPDxVHD42v7Cp8L0foWtfvdbsfFnhqy0nxDNY/ar1baa4trhkDRF0JVsEZU46e1ZP7T3i+b4pfEHwnfeGdE2RpfX9jFbZzO0kZALMRxtYAEccZNX/iT4cfwnr3h2yF757xaohJIOMZArA8ZtqfhzxfY+JdMtVkl03xBc+VE2cEsnFe/nuc5rHifCQTXNOMZO+3Nbr2TZ8Q8Dhoxq06d+ROSXoj5qu/Elr4B+LU/jLwN41FuYrxLi1vLK5KvHIp3AjB7Gvs7Sf8Agttd3ngJ/hv4k8Fx32q3sRs/+EhguQgkR12GSSHbgPySdrYPoK/N27diS2/OR0pmk3LwajDOGIKSKQM+9cUaSilqej7aono9D7++DfiL/hD9Wh1uMIXNuQsgHGSCM817l4I8cadpmmtrtzqWbi7lxHEud0hPTFfK/wAN/EF3faFbyiAyoUBUke3SvY/hjpYu4B4p8TXe2CKQLaRsCfnHOBj7gxyT3xU1E+W1jGnL95c+k/if8em+Hnhi0s5Jo5L66iw8CnJiG3gn07V4j4l/aP8AF1zBLJYfOQmSVGQtcx4w8TX/AMRfE72mmWquxYRxuGIZ/wA65uw8dfEq3fUvCnhr9n7xPfGxuBHdz2OjtIjf7XmYChfx55rgVGL0fQ+ow+Kry0WiOZ1r4k/FfxL4pk106tfQWyMMBQQqgdiuMH8ah8beLdYl8SJrXgUixUwqZT5KoZGwNxOB0JycZ711On/EDRPtbRePPGc/gi5kwlvB4q8OXawXJ4DYktFuFG0kAlwuAQTgVmfErx34L0iBLWH4leDPEGwKEfwxq8d0qhs442IwPsVB68V0+xa0ZrfD1ZX9pqdl8Fv2mb7TntbKRYohE224jjXaGPGT79K9y+IPjrQ7vwsuu2V0pW4hyjI+fmxyK+LdP1/QdQkln0SIG4jAaQRnsa7RPiPc3nwyudGmumXypWcDoUIUelcMqXv2Q/r0oe63cyPiH8SZLwXp1G9YKARGM9xXffsiaVJL8Mr7xZc3RgiOoysqn/lqNqLk+mCD+tfL/iLxPNLaySXk25A5KnucVman+2n450f4YP8ACbwbpy6em2WGW/STMjK7EkgYGDzjNdsabasjyoYxU67qSZW+Jv7UPxN134h6vd6P4rkNnDq876b8ikJGJD5eMj+7tqppv7QPxd8U6ts13xdI6CVrmRvLVW3hcZBA9K81jeVB5rjDMMtWhoksoiurqM/MECdPUiu6rBVpqpU1lHZ9dDx3O3Ny7O7+8rSacp+RkYE1TudLED+dk5XkcV2Eulk53RgEfdxVDVdFL2zOB8wHbvVuNjPms9T2T4EePZ5/C9kk5IiWXyfMXoXABx+or6L8I6jd3ekO7Ws8lvbNF8kSHYzfNgEjv96vEP2Ofhlf/Ej9ljxpf6Np3nah4c8QxTxog+fa8Izj1/1Z/Wuw8J/FHVrPwf5Tav8AZriFiqAnBzgj5hjsCayqNcuglOMZ2PT/AIF6nD4o+IE+oxW6Q7JGkIC5CnPQV714s8OfDt7KHxXJrtxoupsPnubGRo3yOh+U59K+HvAHxe1TwlrYjsZuDId8i5G8ls54r20/F248XaUUmtzI6jYwZjjpXmTU6dRtbM+hwFZtadD1mw+J3iKwsH0S/wDHHhLxhpzmLZa+NdNW4aMJKsmFkUpJlgpjJZzhJH27ThhjfEDxx4W1bTtTgl/ZZ8B2EWoSSZPhi5mgt41dt21ULyHgfKNzMcHk14ze6B4iuJZ7eWMW8saFZF3AkMQcAY/D6Zqj4fbWbb96Lsgsu1wWxyO/NbRrTauepLEUaj96miz4R+G/gzwtD4l1PQ/BtjpJ1GEsILVpHRMEttQyuxHXsRXmnj7UhpnhxmtSUNyuGTPbpXafEHxqmj6ebae/RpApJUPjJ/CvDPiB4yk1aKIpKNiIQwB/2jgflRTjzO7PGxlSF/d0OW8Ya3Ba2LHOCEbgn1rzi10+4mmaebHzvnmtvX7z+3daFnGzbYzyPU1Yj0o8KyYx0rtpwUUeRUlcyZLQ/wAanp1xWjodsUsmAjzvuFBGfSrb6UdpLDtUtnaSRRxJGeDdrmtSNUdNFponG/YGPvS3ugia2P7jtg8V11n4caGLcIhn6VJJo8sVoxdAOOmK6lSSV2YXiz6N/wCCK3haHUrD4r+Gp4s7zpcqqenIuhj9K4T9tX4Iax8IfiTdanp1q8el3kgkKBSAjHr+Ga+gf+CPfw51LwzovjP4iT2zxw61fW1pBvHDiBHdmHtmfH4V9D/tF/s9+H/i74auxqFkk0kkDLtZevBxyOlefKpFTaOlUJShc/K7wfGst5HdPAsm1gcGvWNCF3DCWtd+2SdZHhVfmAB+YfpXB/GH4P8Aij4FeJrq1hSVrBZyF+U7ou+D/jVDRvjlNpsAiuyX+TaGzzUyUZK5ph6kqUrntfiuWwfVl1O31qYPLKHji3BfJdgG2vz168+grhvFni/U3spLqOZUMIw23Ay/p71xWr/G/S7u/aZpmi/dr5u7ncVGBXK+Ifi0l9HPb+aBFI24FRyD+FYOiua56bxvMnYZ4s8V3Wv3f2i4m6Zrm7nT5tV0m/1mQsLextndmHQsBwPbnFNsvP8AE9/DY6YrO8r7diqcnJ4r1/x18Lm8EfACbSWth9r1GSL7U5XlVLjIq1JQ0RyclSac5Hz74K8NzTQPq10pDucpnrXQR6XwSAR6jFbMWipYWcVvEMBVGKs6ZpLTFlODzkcV6EYcyPNc7u6OcTSpZDh1J9gKQ2citDAqHCXh3cdOBXbJ4fjhO6RcY9qw9qC72AAr9tk5x7KKcqTirlczep67pPhbWdUxFbaXO5YgAiI4/lXdeBvgTY6xega5duyRAvJbxrndjkqT+ldP4hnaDUBYWxZVQZIWur+EMNtNLNI74LRkKD+XWvgMfxZi6sLUlyrqfc4LhjCUk5Td2fSP7Gj6S3wS0/TdNWNZ7Oa5W9jQYKu0rMvH+4U/KvV5Z1aI280nDDgV4L+wmy6T4k8Z+GdUY+agtZbcsfvxneOB7Hv7ivbNUeKO/e3eTHy5Bx1r28HXhVw0Zp3ujzJYf2eKlFo81+PP7P3hD4u6JcWd1bgTspAkRBu6cc1+d/xz/Yc8e+C9UkuNMAlsxn51BABJ6Zr9P7zUxBL8snAPauf8V+DPC/jWAxanp5Kty2xgMn16V1RxCV0wrZQ5O8T8cPEfwb+K+n3/ANl/4R64YvgKyxlgfoRmtf4c/spfGD4ieIE0aLw/cwHaWaa5hZIwB7kV+qb/AAj+Hmm3Ia20hVKDB+QZ/PFVtVsvD/hm1f8Asy2SPcOXxzRLFrlempph8oakrnyf8Kv2RfDvwfs4tW8QFbvU8hskfLGR6AimfGCxstd03+xWhJEjdR+leq/EHV0ubt5I5DsA5yfSvLtVRb2Zp5ZPl/hFeRjMwlQXMnqe0svp8nI1dHhWu/D3UrENvUFFOFwOcVnaTaS2UrGWErx1KmvX/EMcckxhReAvPNc1dWFsrMrYP410YXiOpypVInj4jh6jq6bscXczBVJkY9OtcfPKS0hiJBSeZicemP8ACvVLrQ9DuG3ypt9CDiud1H4QS3xkbRdVjZ3DlY5F28keuTmvVp59hK0bSdjyquSYuk/d1R//2Q=='

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You read the file in python as bytes but you do a bunch of imaging compression stuff in java

Comment: You'll probably get the same b64 string as python if you just use `Base64.encodeToString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file")), Base64.NO_WRAP);`

Comment: Can you give me a function that I can use for checking?

Comment: How can I use this `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file"))` as an argument on Android ( java code )?

Comment: I have no idea how you access your image on android, but you'll need to read the file directly anyway, not process is through Bitmap

Comment: My guess is that android is adding some metadata to the image, try comparing the 2 files to check if they're indeed equal.Your question also shows how unnecessarily complicated java can be compared to python.

Comment: @Artog I have posted the code, as you can see I have used R.drawable to get image from the drawable folder and convert it to bitmap

Comment: @PedroLobito For that reason, I faced many problems when I try to get predictions from an image using Tensorflow lite compared to python.

Comment: They are not two files, it was just the same image using on Android, I have used with python script.

Comment: Headers correct but you got wrong content if open "X" file. *Bitmap* open and *file* open aren't have same output. Android required open as *.txt* format with no additional converting for equality. Python read bytes without any encodings `open(image, "rb")` but android got `BMP` coding `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565`. Binary method isn't equal to `open with type`.

Comment: @dsgdfg , If that, Can you give me a suggestion instead of comparing the base64 encoded string to check if the same image is used on Android and on python code?  Other question, Did this situation can influence the results of predictions of landmarks?

Comment: Which platform compared two image? Android or python or both ? Quick way is *`MD5`* for don't waste any resources!

Comment: I have explained what I need, I want to compare basecode64 encoded String of two images ( same image ) using python and java ( Android Studio ) to found the original problem

Comment: if you don't need pixel differences check `CRC`, `LRC` etc. !

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you say